# haw to find the values of binary numbers in octal?

Tags: binary

what is the value of 101111.0111 of base 2 (binary) in octal(base 8) 
we know that in order to translate from binary to octal we need to group the bits in groups of three and the value is going to be in octal.
can anyone please explain for me haw to convert 101111.0111 from binary to octal.

Comment: So, you've got it... pad the beginning with zeroes to make the number of digits before the decimal point (binary point?) a multiple of 3, and similarly pad the end.  You get $101\;111\;.\;011\;100$.  Then translate $101$ to $5$, $111$ to $7$, $011$ to $3$, and $100$ to $4$, giving you $57.34$ in octal.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to form 3-digit groups adding leading zeroes to the integer part and trailing zeroes to the fractional part to make both of these parts containing number of digits divisible by $3$. In your case you have $101111.0111 = 101\ 111.011\ 100$. Each group before the dot refers to $8^0, 8^1$ and so on from right to left, each group after the dot refers to $8^{-1}, 8^{-2}$ and so on from left to right. So, here we have $101_2 * 8^1 + 111_2*8^0 + 011_2 * 8^{-1} + 100_2*8^{-2} = 5*8^1 + 7 * 8^0 + 3 * 8^{-1} + 4 * 8^{-2} = 57.34_8$